# Using Holoviews NdOverlay with cuDF or cupy

Tags: python, holoviews, cupy, cudf, datashader

I am trying to render a line plot with a dataframe of ~25000 time series samples (each with 226 time steps). I have had success using this guide on plotting large datasets with Holoviews NdOverlay:

https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html (specifically the multidimensional plots section)

```
import datashader as ds
import holoviews as hv
import holoviews.operation.datashader as hd

lines = {i: hv.Curve(cp.asarray(df.iloc[i].values)) for i in range(len(df))}
lineoverlay = hv.NdOverlay(lines)
plot = hd.datashade(lineoverlay, pixel_ratio=1, line_width=1, aggregator=ds.count()).opts(width=600)
```

I then take the mean of the dataframe and use hv.Curve to plot this `mean = hv.Curve((x, df_mean.values[0]))` and overlay the two plots.

```
plot2 = hv.Overlay([plot, mean]).collate()
```

The issue is it takes an extremely long time to render so I thought I would try using the Rapids AI gpu accelerated cuDF and cupy packages. Regardless of the method I try both seems to fail on the dictionary construction.

```
import cuml
import cupy as cp
import cudf

df = cudf.from_pandas(df)
lines =  {i: hv.Curve(df.iloc[i].values) for i in range(len(df))}
```

or

```
lines = {i: hv.Curve(cp.asarray(df.iloc[i].values)) for i in range(len(df))}
```

both give the error:

```
holoviews.core.data.interface.DataError: None of the available storage backends were able to support the supplied data format.
```

Any input or other ways of going about the problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get it work, via converting the lines to a single cudf dataframe, as that's the format hv.Curve seems to work with.

Following is one way you could plot the requested charts using cudf and holoviews.

I am using the `time_series()` function to generate data mentioned on https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html.

```py
df = cudf.DataFrame({"x"+str(i): cudf.Series(time_series(N=10000, S0=200+np.random.rand())) for i in range(num_ks)})
lines = {i: hv.Curve(df[[i]].reset_index()) for i in df.columns}
lineoverlay = hv.NdOverlay(lines, kdims='k')
```

[image]

Generating the overlaying mean line:

```py
mean = hv.Curve(cudf.DataFrame({'x':df.mean(axis=1)}).reset_index())
hv.Overlay([lineoverlay, mean]).collate().opts(width=800)
```

[image]